# Find the missing rise that makes these lines perpendicular.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, slope

The slopes of two lines are
$m_1 = -3$ and $m_2 = k/4$.

Find the value of *k* that makes these lines perpendicular.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Do you know the relationship between slopes of perpendicular lines?

Comment: Try doing this. Take a sheet of paper and draw the x- and y- axes. Then draw a line from to origin with a slope of -3. Next, rotate the piece of paper clockwise $90^{\circ}$. Now, with your knowledge of triangular geometry,  try to determine the relationship between the line, and one perpendicular to it.

Answer (score 1):

If two lines are perpendicular, the product of their slopes is $-1$.

(For proof, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48713/product-of-slopes-is-1-iff-perpendicular-proof-from-first-principles).)

Can you solve $-3k/4=-1$ for $k$?

Answer (score 0):

We know that 2 lines, $l_1$, $l_2$ with slopes $m_1$ and $m_2$ are perpendicular when 
$$m_1m_2=-1$$ 
Since it is given that $m_1=-3$ and $m_2=\frac{k}{4}$,
$$-3\left(\frac{k}{4}\right)=-1$$
$$k=\frac{4}{3}$$
Therefore the value of $k$ that makes those lines perpendicular is $\frac{4}{3}$

Comment: why did you say $k=\dfrac43$ and then the value of $k$ is $\frac34$?!